# Bind Windows menu item to shortcut like macOS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I work on a Mac at work, and my coworker has a Windows PC. We're both using Adobe XD for design. There's a particular menu item that's super useful and I've bound it to a custom shortcut via Mac's Preferences > App Shortcut feature.

[image: mac app shortcuts]

Is there a way to do this on Windows, even through a 3rd party program?

Comment: I am using Photoshop CS5 and in there you can make custom macro's. These macro's can then be given a hotkey. If you make a macro performing that specific action, even if its just opening a menu, that should work. I don't know which program you are talking about though and if it has support for macro's. That's why this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: @LPChip yeah can't have Macros in XD. Updated my question specifying that 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you can bind custom shortcuts using the application itself in most cases.

However, in this case, you can either use a program like AutoHotKey by writing scripts to navigate the menus for this action automatically.

An AutoHotKey script for this exact bind would go as such:

```
+#r::
 // do advanced thing involving moving the cursor, clicking, etc. or sending arrow keys
return
```

Reference documents:

[MouseMove Function](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm)
[MouseClick function](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm)
[Send Function](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Comment: Ah interesting. I'll have to look that up. It simply would be a menu command in Adobe XD as such: Object > Align to Pixel Grid

Comment: The majority of classic (meaning Windows Forms, not the newer UWP or WPF) Windows programs have a Menu bar containing a File menu, an Edit menu, a Help/About menu, etc.

Comment: Could you link me to the docs page for doing such a thing please? I can't find anything about +#r, there's a lot... O_o I simply would want to run a command from a menu in Adobe XD: Object > Align to Pixel Grid. I'm guessing using keyboard commands would be easiest.

Comment: +#r:: means "when Shift + Windows/Command/Super + r is pressed" (basically when it detects that keystroke)

Comment: Found this too: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMenuSelectItem.htm. Thanks again, think I can trial and error from here. :)

Comment: @jaminroe Don't forget to mark my answer as solution if it solved this!

Comment: yup I did! I wanted to wait until i try it, but I'm positive it will solve my question. Thanks again! I'll follow up with my own answer too, as to what I did as well once I get it to work.

Comment: Great! Keep me posted!